# How to pass command into xargs that contains pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, sh

I have relatively short question, how do you do something like this:

```
ls -1a | xargs -L1 (find ./'{}' -type f | wc -l)
```

(it should basically count number of files in each folder within current folder)

(more precisely how to fit `find ./'{}' -type f | wc -l` into `ls -1a | xargs -L1 (HERE)`

Thank you in advance!

## Edit

I'm using this command to get number of files in every subsequent folder, i.e. result should look like

```
2134123 # Folder #1
1234231 # Folder #2 
12341   # Folder #3
2343224 # Folder #4
```

Comment: I can't tell if you want a count of all regular files "below" the current directory or some kind of output describing the number of regular files in each directory "below" the current one. Please update your question to include exact desired output.

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself saying something like "do ... in each ...", consider using a loop instead of a super-long one-liner if you want your code to be maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [Why *not* parse ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

```
find . -type d | while read d; do 
  echo $d $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
done
```

Comment: This will give only one value, I want separate value for every folder in current directory @vintnes

Comment: @Lu4 Please update your question to include *exact* desired output.